# should database verify if user is authorized to perform action

Tags: sql, database

Should database be verifying if user is authorized to perform certain action?

Two examples:

1)User is enrolled in 30 teams max and it can see scoresheet of these teams only. I'm passing in userid and teamid to the stored procedure and fetching the scoresheet only if user is authorized to view the scoresheet. Is it more appropriate to only pass in only teamid and check beforehand what all teams user is enrolled in? Should I do both?

2)Currently I'm passing in userid of the poster and the commentid of the comment to be deleted and I'm deleting comment only if both criteria is met - userid matches to the poster id and commentid matches to the commentid - just to make sure user is deleting his own comment and not somebody else's. Is it an overkill?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple layers of validation is best practice and it doesn't seem like your methods would cause additional overhead. Just make sure to limit connecting to the database once, I've found that the most costly part of running database queries is the connection and cursors.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174437%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Security experts will tell you that *No amount of security is enough*! But at the same time you have to find a **balance** b/w *security* and unnecessary layers of protection that are bound to affect your application's *performance*.

Answering your **2nd** question first: It is a good idea to pass both *userid* as well as *commentid*, and matching both, so that you accidentally don't delete all comments by a particular user.

Coming to your **1st** question now: As I understand it, you want users only part of the team to be able to view the team's scoresheet, right? In order to do so passing only the *teamid* of all the teams the user is a part of will do. I am not sure what you mean by *authorization* here!

**NOTE:** 
I have answered your question from a theoretical view with no idea about your *Table structure* or whats written in your *Stored Procedures*.

Comment: The security experts I've interacted with generally lean towards *balance* instead of the more absolute doctrine.

Comment: Then you have been in the company of far **saner** security experts than myself my friend @udoprog.

Comment: 1st question: What I mean is there could be a bunch of activities like scoresheets, articles etc being posted for teams and when user requests any of these, I want there to be a check whether he's authorized to view it (which depends on what all teams he's part of). So instead of passing userid, you think I should pass in teamid's (of the user) and I should store these teamids as session variable or something?

Comment: Absolutely! Fetching each user first on the basis of *userid* and then checking for the teams the user is part of will be computationally more expensive. Faster approach would be to pass the user's *teamid*.

Answer (score 0):

Your frontend is a much more friendlier (libraries, frameworks, best practices) environment to implement whatever access restrictions or authorization that you could possibly have in mind. Adding another layer inside the database just adds a lot of complexity and duplicate implementation of your access restrictions.

I would only consider doing it if clients connect and execute commands directly against the database.

So, rely on the ids provided by the application and spend your energy on sanitizing user input and implementing a sane authentication model. You will need it.